# JAVA type mismatch errors when using Class.forName on generics

Tags: java, generics

Please have a look at the following code:

```
Class<? extends List> class1;
Class<? extends List<?>> class2;
Class<? extends List<? extends Object>> class3;
class1 = class2.asSubclass(List.class);     // 1. OK
class1 = class3.asSubclass(List.class);     // 2. OK
class2 = class1.asSubclass(List.class);     // 3. Error Type Mismatch
class2 = class3.asSubclass(List.class);     // 4. Error Type Mismatch
class3 = class1.asSubclass(List.class);     // 5. Error Type Mismatch
class3 = class2.asSubclass(List.class);     // 6. Error Type Mismatch
String className;
class1 = Class.forName(className);          // 7. Error Type Mismatch
class2 = Class.forName(className);          // 8. Error Type Mismatch
class3 = Class.forName(className);          // 9. Error Type Mismatch
class1 = Class.forName(className).asSubclass(List.class);   // 10. OK
class2 = Class.forName(className).asSubclass(List.class);   // 11. Error Type Mismatch
class3 = Class.forName(className).asSubclass(List.class);   // 12. Error Type Mismatch
```

1., 2. and 10. are OK, and I like 10. in particular because of its cleanness, but I do not like using RAW type, so I went for wildcard.

Sadly, all the others failed because of Type Mismatch error, unless I do a cast plus `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` combo.

Is this a case where one has to use RAW type to avoid casting and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Otherwise how to you fix 11. and 12.? (forget about 3. to 9., they are just here to demo different combinations, my code has no use of them)

Comment: `className` is an empty string. `static Class<?> forName(String className)` Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name. What do you expect to happen when you pass an un-instantiated variable?

Comment: Thats not the issue here. I can change the above to `String className = "a.b.c";` still the same errors as those are Compile time errors, not runtime errors.

Comment: is a.b.c a variable in your run-time?

Comment: No just a random string to say that it doesn't affect the examples in my question.

Comment: Well if the string you pass does not associate to a given interface or class it would probably behave similarly to passing nothing at all...

Comment: I can handle runtime errors, as this question is about those compile time errors, please focus on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a fundamental limitation of the language due to aspects of type erasure. `Class` objects representing non-raw generic types do not exist and cannot be obtained or created. The following expressions all produce the same object, even under comparison by `==`:

```
new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass();
new ArrayList<String>().getClass();
Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList");
ArrayList.class;
```

And this throws a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList<Integer>");
```

So yes, you have to use the raw type.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please also comment on using wildcard + cast + `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: @user1589188 That approach is technically valid, but either would not be useful or would eliminate unchecked warnings from other places where the artificially casted object is used, potentially resulting in unsafe casts that don't get noticed.